# Async , Await returns Promise { <pending> } node js. Want boolean in return

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, async-await, fetch

I am trying to use fetch API to get my data from a url. I am able to fetch the data from url and perform operations with it. The issue i have is my return statement returns promise pending instead of returning true or false. I am able to use console.log to print result with no problem. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function load(CLIENT_ID) {
  let response = await fetch('<url-hidden>');
  let data = await response.json();
  let resp_data = checkClientExist(data, CLIENT_ID)
  return resp_data
}

function checkClientExist(data, CLIENT_ID) {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].CLIENT_ID === CLIENT_ID) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

console.log(load("fa000")) // Returns undefined want it to return either true or false(i.e resp_data from above)

load("fa000").then(response => {
  console.log(response)
}) // works fine
```

Comment: The example you have in the last line, the one that works, that's how you do it.  Alternatively, if you're in the context of an `async` function, you can `await load("fa000")`.  But asynchronous is just that... asynchronous.  The `load` function doesn't return a boolean, it returns a `Promise`.